# Fetch Outlook calendar events between two dates

Tags: laravel, outlook-calendar

I have implemented outlook calendar API in Laravel. I am getting all the calendar events.
But now i want to fetch calendar events between two specific dates i.e. monthwise. So what are the keys for start datetime and end datetime. Because at some places it is given start_time, at some places startDateTime and some are using $filter.
Below is my query parameter array

```
$eventsQueryParams = array (
    // Only return Subject, Start, and End fields
    "\$select" => "subject,start,end",
    // Sort by Start, oldest first
    "\$orderby" => "Start/DateTime",
    // Return at most 10 results
    "\$top" => "10"
);
```

To use filter i tried below code but i am getting 400 Bad Request

```
"\$filter" => "start/dateTime ge ".date(DATE_ISO8601,strtotime('2018-04-01 00:00:00'))." and end/dateTime le ".date(DATE_ISO8601,strtotime('2018-04-30 00:00:00')),
```

Now what should i add to my $eventsQueryParams so that i can fetch calendar events month-wise.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried following code and it worked for me.

```
$eventsQueryParams = array (
    // Only return Subject, Start, and End fields
    "\$select" => "subject,start,end",
    // Sort by Start, oldest first
    "\$orderby" => "Start/DateTime",
    // Return at most 10 results
    "\$top" => "10",
    "\$filter" => "Start/DateTime ge '".date('Y-m-d',strtotime('2018-04-01 00:00:00'))."' and End/DateTime le '".date('Y-m-d',strtotime('2018-04-30 00:00:00'))."'",
);
```

Initially quotes were missing for date.
Before changes my code

```
$eventsQueryParams = array (
    // Only return Subject, Start, and End fields
    "\$select" => "subject,start,end",
    // Sort by Start, oldest first
    "\$orderby" => "Start/DateTime",
    // Return at most 10 results
    "\$top" => "10",
    "\$filter" => "Start/DateTime ge ".date('Y-m-d',strtotime('2018-04-01 00:00:00'))." and End/DateTime le ".date('Y-m-d',strtotime('2018-04-30 00:00:00')),
    );
```